# PHP match typo with correct value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know if it is possible in PHP, but I would like to check in an array for values that are correct based on what a user might be typing and in case they type it wrong. For example I could have an array like this:

```
$correct_values = array('accounts','users','cheesecake','banana');
```

If a user submits a string saying for example `acounts` (note only one 'c') then I would like to go through the `$correct_values`-array and see if there is something similar and return the value - in this case `return $correct_values[0]`. If the user submits `banan` it should return `$correct_values[3]`.

Is there an existing function in PHP that allows me to detect this? Or would I need to create a `$common_typos`-array containing all the common mistakes and return an array key for `$correct_values`?

Comment: This is a very tough task, no perfect solution exists. If you have an idea about the language, then you can take a look at the sound functions php offers. They actually can be used as a kind of "fuzzy search". So functions like `soundex()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially what the [`levenshtein($input, $entry)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) method is intended for. In your use case, you'd iterate through each entry within `$correct_values`, calculate the Levenshtein distance between the two strings, and choose the one with the minimal distance (or return no result if it exceeds a certain value, 2 for example).

---

Example:

```
/**
 * Returns the closest Levenshtein match
 * @param string $input 
 * @param array $correct_values
 * @param int $threshold
 * @return null|string Either the closest-matching string or null
 */
public function getCloseMatch($input, $correct_values = array(), $threshold = 2) {
    $closest_match = array('value' => null, 'distance' => null);
    foreach($correct_values as $value) {
        $distance = levenshtein($input, $value);
        if($distance === 0) {
            // Great, we got an exact match!
            return $value;
        }

        if($closest_match['distance'] === null || ($distance >= 0 && $distance < $closest_match['distance'])) {
            $closest_match['value'] = $value;
            $closest_match['distance'] = $distance;
        }
    }

    if($closest_match['distance'] === null || $closest_match['value'] === null || $closest_match['distance'] > $threshold) {
        return null;
    } 
    return $closest_match['value'];

}
```

Comment: Wonderful! That is EXACTLY what I have been looking for.. I have never heard of this one before - but I gonna dig into it right away!

Comment: @Dimser I'm glad it's useful; I've updated my answer with an example that passes in an input string, an array of values to attempt to match on and a threshold limit (if, say, the difference between the input and the array is just too much) as an example

Comment: Quick question.. In your function - would it be an idea to have an `if (in_array($input, $correct_values))` check before the `foreach` loop to exclude any unnecessary processing? I believe it would return the same as the `if($distance === 0)` check.

Comment: @Dimser Certainly, and it would short-circuit a bit of the process (especially if you have a LOT of entries in $correct_values). Calculating the Levenshtein distance isn't the cheapest computationally (`O(len-n * len-m)`)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) - it'll give you a number saying how much letters you need to change in the search term to match a correct value. You can then pick the correct value with the smallest Hamming distance.